# I can't make a request to an API in Repl.it

Tags: javascript, node.js, replit

I'm creating a discord bot in JavaScript and I make a request to an API, when I run the bot on my computer everything works fine, and I wanted to automate my bot so I moved it to Repl.it, the problem it's that on Repl.it, my requests don't work, it tells me that my IP is banned [here the result of my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BtnW.png), so I wonder if there is a solution to circumvent this ban.
Here is my code:

```
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(...args));

module.exports = async function player(name, message, channel){

var headers = {
    'API-KEY' : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}

var link = 'https://api.rinaorc.com/player/'+name

var fetched = await fetch(link, {method: 'GET', headers: headers})

fetched = await fetched.json()

if(fetched['message'] === 'Player not found'){
    return message.reply('Joueur introuvable')
}
```

Comment: If you find repl.it banned, perhaps use something else.

Comment: lots of people are trying to host their bots on repl.it which leads to lots of requests and bots stop working. You can try heroku for hosting your bot but other than that you have to host it on your computer